# Xamairn forms: Video is not fully filled in webview on ios platforrm

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using `webview` for showing HTML data(has video) on the UI. It is working fine on android but on ios, the video is **not fully filled horizontally**.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code:**

```
string htmlData = "<p style=\"text-align: center; \"><iframe webkitallowfullscreen=\"\" mozallowfullscreen=\"\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/641943496\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" class=\"note-video-clip\"></iframe></p>\r\n<h3 style=\"text-align: center; \">The Catholic Brain series \"Advent with Father John\" can be <a href=\"https://www.catholicbrain.com/edu/videos/category/262/tag/602\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"msofficelink-link-handled\">found here</a>.<br></h3>\r\n<h4>Today&#39;s Gospel - Adapted from Matthew 4:18-22</h4>";
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    ios_web_view.IsVisible = true;
    ios_web_view.Url = htmlData.Replace("&#39;", "'");
}

if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{
    android_web_view.IsVisible = true;
    string description = htmlData.Replace("&#39;", "'");
    var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    htmlSource.Html = description.Replace("width=\"640\" height=\"360\"", "width=\"350\" height=\"350\"");
    android_web_view.Source = htmlSource;
}
```

I am using a custom renderer to increase the text size. I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqeQK1FaYmJ2dwdtcbpULNUZ3t4xKp86/view?usp=sharing) for reference. I need to fil the video horizontally in ios.

**Update: 29-12-2021**

I am able to create a sample project with the issue. I tested it on my side and content is showing on the ios part. My issue is video is not filling horizontally.
Sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17p_yEB7wsUozkA6kJV_jcvE-MAu3LGIS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can create two htmlData strings and set the height and width, and use the corresponding strings according to the platform you are using.

Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string htmlData = "<p style=\"text-align: center; \"><iframe webkitallowfullscreen=\"\" mozallowfullscreen=\"\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/641943496\" data-wf-ignore=\"true\" width=\"900\" height=\"360\" class=\"note-video-clip\"></iframe></p>\r\n<h3 style=\"text-align: center; \">The Catholic Brain series \"Advent with Father John\" can be <a href=\"https://www.catholicbrain.com/edu/videos/category/262/tag/602\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"msofficelink-link-handled\">found here</a>.<br></h3>\r\n<h4>Today&#39;s Gospel - Adapted from Matthew 4:18-22</h4>";
        string htmlData1 = "<p style=\"text-align: center; \"><iframe webkitallowfullscreen=\"\" mozallowfullscreen=\"\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/641943496\" width=\"400\" height=\"360\" class=\"note-video-clip\"></iframe></p>\r\n<h3 style=\"text-align: center; \">The Catholic Brain series \"Advent with Father John\" can be <a href=\"https://www.catholicbrain.com/edu/videos/category/262/tag/602\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"msofficelink-link-handled\">found here</a>.<br></h3>\r\n<h4>Today&#39;s Gospel - Adapted from Matthew 4:18-22</h4>";

        myviewview.IsVisible = true;
        string description = htmlData.Replace("&#39;", "'");
        string description1 = htmlData1.Replace("&#39;", "'");
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource(); 
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
        {
            htmlSource.Html = description;
            myviewview.Source = htmlSource;
        }
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            htmlSource.Html = description1;
            myviewview.Source = htmlSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only I need to update the width=\"900\" or do I need to add data-wf-ignore=\"true\" before width value?

Comment: Is it working on your side?

Comment: According to my test, it works without ata-wf-ignore=\"true\" width. You can copy and paste it into your code to try it.

Comment: I am getting a white screen on ios, is it happen on ur side?

Comment: Please check if you have given network permissions.

Comment: In ios what network permissions do we need to give?

Comment: Add in info.plist:<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
    </dict>

Comment: Added that but still getting white screen

Comment: According to my test, I provided the background code above, and then there is only one Webview in the xaml page, and then add the network permissions I provided in iOS->info.plist. It turned out that everything is normal, I am not sure if it is your other It is caused by the code, so I suggest that you can create a new project to try.

Comment: I am able to create a sample project with the issue. I tested it on my side and content is showing on the ios part. Could you please check? My issue is video is not filling horizontally.
Sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17p_yEB7wsUozkA6kJV_jcvE-MAu3LGIS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is the problem of the video source. The width and height have been set in the internal html page of your webview, so you cannot set it externally. You can try to modify the html code settings of the original video to solve this problem.